# Email scheduling in C# (ASP .NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Hi want to send birthday emails to all employees which details are stored in database.
I found Quartz .NET library
but can't understand the code exactly.
can anyone please give me some sample code.?

Comment: Is your database hosted with SQL Server? If so you can make a new job in sql and send the emails from inside the job code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I heard about Quartz. It looks cool.

Found this stackoveflow thread [How to use Quartz.net with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Further to Ives - answer:

What about from their website:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/examples/index.html

This blog maybe of help as well..

http://blog.goyello.com/2009/09/21/how-to-use-quartz-net-in-pro-way/

Stack Overflow Question
[Sending Periodic Mail according to user's Setting in ASP.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961850/sending-periodic-mail-according-to-users-setting-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is something similar [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prvn_131971/BirthdayWishScheduler02022006012557AM/BirthdayWishScheduler.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can code a small console application, a simple database with 1 table as you said which keeps dates,names and other details you need.

Simply select all rows which meets condition

```
Birthday == DateTime.Now
```

and mail them in a loop.

You can add this exe as a scheduled job with a few clicks and set it to run every day. It would also be a good practice for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script file (possibly in VBScript as a VBS file) and schedule that script file in the Windows Task Scheduler (say every morning 8 AM) on the server level.